# UiPath: Windows Nodes for ASRobots Instead of Linux?

Tags: windows, automation, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot

I've successfully configured and deployed UiPath using the default provided quick-start templates.

However, I'm interested in utilizing Windows nodes for my ASRobots instead of the default Linux instances deployed by the templates.

Has anyone attempted this or can confirm if UiPath supports such a configuration? Additionally, I'm curious if there's any documentation available regarding this setup.

Any insights or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is ASRobots? And what is the question? SO is not for opinions btw. So make clear what the question is about.